# Some Java 8 features working in Android SDK 23 while others don't?

Tags: java, android, java-8

I built a demo app in Android with a minimum SDK version 24. After I finished, I was informed that we only have test devices with SDK 23 (I was using my own device to develop) and that I would need to downgrade. To do this, I changed the minSdkVersion in my app.gradle from 24 to 23. Now, I am getting errors for all occurences of forEach (as expected), but I am still able to use lambda expressions, even though those are also a Java 8 feature. As far as I know, I have not added anything like Retrolambda to my project.

Here is my app.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myfirm.rocketchatdemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // RocketChat SDK
    compile('com.rocketchat.core:rocketchat-core:0.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxandroid
    // Reactive Java
    compile group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxandroid', version: '2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'

    // Chat Kit
    // compile 'com.github.stfalcon:chatkit:0.2.2'

    // ChatMessageView
    compile 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:1.3.5'

    // Google Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'                        // this line must be included to integrate with Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
}
```

This is incredibly confusing to me, either both should work or neither! In addition, my app does not function properly anymore, and I thought that maybe some residual Java 8 code might be the cause of this. That's how I stumbled on this.

Have I maybe missed some configuration to properly convert my app to SDK 23?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Supported Java 8 Language Features and APIs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features) documentation Lambda expressions do not require a certain minSdkVersion version.

This also applies to:

- Lambda expressions
- Method References
- Type Annotations (compile time only)
- Default and static interface methods
- Repeating annotations

Comment: Oh well alright then. Kinda interested to know how that works, but this answers my question :)